# "Road" when referring to an unphysical thing

Tags: word-usage

Can "road" be used in the following situation:

The original sentence:

> They got angry that they were not willing to hear any excuse.

The shortened version:

> They got angry unwilling to hear any excuse.

And the update summary was written like this:

> Shortened the **road** for you.

Its intended meaning is that there were many unnecessary words that could be omitted in order to get to the consequence of that group anger **faster**.

*("you" refers to the readers)*

So, is that considered as an acceptable and correct usage of "road"? Can it be used in a sarcastic or humorous way? If not, what would the substitute word be?

---

I have searched for the possible usages of "road" and looked for example sentences but found nothing that supports my usage above.

Here is what I found in [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/road)

---

P.S.

For future visitors, the shortened version above is NOT correct, and this is how it can be written correctly:

**They got angry, unwilling to hear any excuse.**

*(Notice the comma)*

Or

**They got angry and were unwilling to hear any excuse.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A road can be a literal, physical road, on the ground, that leads from one place to another, or the word can be used figuratively to mean a process, task, or experience. If I have completed a difficult task I might say "This has been a long and rocky road".

Note: both the original sentence and the suggested shortened version are ungrammatical.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. `They became angry that they refused to hear any excuse.` - `They became angry unwilled to hear any excuse.` — are they now grammatically correct?

Comment: They are worse.

Comment: I'm not giving up, but I need to know what is wrong with them at least.

Comment: "They got **so** angry that they were not willing to hear any excuse."  is a possible correction for the first one. You should try to shorten it yourself, but do not use these comments as a lesson space.